# How to export all archived yahoo messenger chat history quickly?

Tags: history, yahoo-messenger

Currently I have to open chat history, clicking on each nick to see the chat content and keep clicking load more to see more

That is very bothering.

How to export all chat entries quickly?

Comment: Similar question is open on Yahoo Answer http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110813050003AAvTBwy